# not able to run some command in gnome terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server, gnome-terminal

I have installed Ubuntu server 14.04 on virtualbox. Then I installed packages like ruby and rails using RVM. Then I started my development in ROR. 

After some time I have installed Gnome on ubuntu server. I have used this guide
http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-gui-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-gnome/

Now the probem is that I am not able to access rails, ruby commands from gnome terminal. I dont know it seems weird. I can run commands by going to non gui terminal (Ctrl + Shift + 1), but not able to do so in gnome terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnome shell doesn't have local variables set unless it's set to run as a login shell.

1. Open your **"Gnome Terminal"**
2. Click on **"Edit"**
3. Click on **"Profile Preferences"**
4. Click on top tab **"Title and Command"**
5. Check the check-box that says **"Run command as login shell"**
6. Close the "Profile Preferences" with the **"Close Button"**
7. **Restart "Gnome Terminal"**

**RVM** relies heavily on your home directory local variables from **.bashrc** and **.bash_profile**.  But by default the gnome terminal won't load them.  This is why you need to set the terminal to **Run command as a login shell**.